# Exposing properties in Composite Controls vs ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

The common way to expose child controls' properties in CompositeControl is following:

```
public class MyControl : CompositeControl {
    private TextBox _box;
    public override short TabIndex
    {
        get 
        { 
            EnsureChildControls();
            return _box.TabIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            _box.TabIndex = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Clear();
        _box = new TextBox {ID = "box"};
        Controls.Add(_box);
    }
// ...
```

}

Is that approach correct? Because since EnsureChildControls adds TextBox to control collection and therefore, triggers its ViewState tracking, so for declarative constructs like this:

```
<uc:MyControl ID="My" runat="server" TabIndex="10"  />
```

ViewState is unnecessarily cluttered (or is it not?)